# When iterating through a list using zip with a break statement it returns every second value

Tags: python, loops, break

```
with open("dict_data.txt") as f:
    word_list = [i.replace("\n","").lower() for i in f.readlines()]

possible_words = word_list
search = "model"

for word in word_list:
    for i in zip(word, search):
        print(i)

    if i[0] != i[1]:
        possible_words.remove(word)
        break

print(possible_words)
```

possible_word copies the values of word list, when i loop through to check if the word is not the same as the guess it should remove it from possible words. But when I print possible words it is every second word from word list.

Comment: `possible_words = word_list` is not a deep copy, right?  Maybe try `possible_words = word_list[:]`.

Comment: But `possible_words` and `word_list` are synonyms. There is a rule of thumb that says to never modify a container you are iterating over. Did you mean: `possible_words = word_list[:]`?

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: Awesome Thank you Fiddling Bits, quamrana I was not aware of this. This seems to have solved the problem